# FileInboundAdapter - Setting a new Trigger during run time

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am using Spring integration 3.0.0. We have a requirement to change the polling interval dynamically during run time.
I have followed the below approach, set up a inbound adapter with a poller that polls for every 5 minutes. I have used Cron because we want to have the advanced scheduling caprability (i.e we ay change the poller to poll only during certain time of the day)

During run time, I got the reference to the adapter, stop the adapter, create a new crontrigger with new expression, set the new trigger to adapter and start the adapter.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInboundAdapter"
    channel="filesIn" directory="C:\\TEMP\\input\\">
    <int:poller id="poller" cron="0 0/5 * * * *"
        error-channel="errorChannel" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>


    SourcePollingChannelAdapter sourcePollingChannelAdapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) context
            .getBean("fileInboundAdapter");
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("0 0/10 * * * *");
    sourcePollingChannelAdapter.stop();
    sourcePollingChannelAdapter.setTrigger(cronTrigger);
    sourcePollingChannelAdapter.start();
```

The approach is working fine.

But in forum, one of the topic related to the same issue(http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/113138-problems-while-trying-to-modify-polling-rate-on-runtime) , the Spring developers advised not to change the Trigger reference at the run time but instead create a own implementation of the trigger.

1. Can anyone please explain why we shouldn't change the Trigger reference at run time?
2. Is there any flaw in the above mentioned approach
3. I want to have the new Cron take effect immediately. i.e Cancel the current scheduled task and schedule a new one with the new Cron expression. Is it possible using the Custom Trigger approach?

Appreciate your help.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your use-case and your code:

```
sourcePollingChannelAdapter.stop();
sourcePollingChannelAdapter.setTrigger(cronTrigger);
sourcePollingChannelAdapter.start();
```

it's really correct to do that such a way. That's because `CronTrigger` isn't so simple to customize, because all of its properties are `final`. And from other side it won't be so easy to implement something similar in the any `CustomTrigger` implementation.

The only good benefit of a `CustomTrigger` that you don't create a new object each time, when you want to change the polling period, and because there wouldn't be a reason to `stop/start` your endpoint for changing that value.

Comment: Your technique is the only way to immediately change the polling behavior. Using a [dynamic trigger](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/dynamic-poller), as discussed in the forum article, only takes effect after the next poll because of the way Spring `Trigger`s work.

Comment: Thanks Artem and Gary. I have one more question. If i stop the adapter when it is polling for a file arrival, Will there be any potential loss of message? i.e what happens if the poller stops(because i stopped the adapter) when it is processing a file message.

Comment: the code looks like `this.runningTask.cancel(true);`, so, there is really some case when your task will rejected. To avoid that you can add `task-executor` to the `<poller>` or make the `channel` isn't `direct`.